# What does typeof x === 'undefined' do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Found this in our code. What's the difference between:

```
if (typeof isValid === 'undefined') {
```

and

```
if (isValid === 'undefined') {
```

Why would anyone use the first one, I don't understand how this makes sense?

Comment: if `isValid` is equal to `'undefined'` there's absolutely no way it has a type of undefined

Comment: The first one checks if `isValid` is `undefined`. The second checks if `isValid` has *the string value* `"undefined"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
if (typeof isValid === 'undefined') {
```

checks to see if the *type* of `isValid` is `"undefined"`. It could be `"undefined"` because either A) `isValid` is a variable with the value `undefined` in it, or B) It's an undeclared identifier.

This:

```
if (isValid === 'undefined') {
```

checks to see if the variable `isValid` contains the string `"undefined"`. The variable must exist (e.g., be declared), or a `ReferenceError` is thrown.

You see the first in situations where the author isn't sure the variable `isValid` has been declared, or because they're worried that `undefined` may have been redefined in the scope where the code occurs, or because a **long** time ago they were worried that the `undefined` in one *realm* (loosely: window/tab) and the `undefined` in another realm wouldn't be `===` to each other. (If that was ever true, it hasn't been for at least a decade.)

Comment: Would you mind wielding your hammer on such questions? The kind of issue OP is facing has been raised many times before.

Comment: I agree with @PaulStenne. Don't just try to gain more "reputation" with this kind of questions that were asked and answered before.

Comment: @PaulStenne - If someone points to a good dupetarget for it, yeah, absolutely and I do typically a dozen or more times a day. I don't know of a **good** dupetarget for this particular question, asking the difference between these particular two tests, but if you do please point it out and I'm happy to pile on. :-) (I don't think the current one is good at all, but I don't disagree enough to reopen either.)

Answer (score -2):

`if (typeof isValid === 'undefined') {` means that you want to check if the variable has any value or not, whereas `if (isValid === 'undefined') {` means that you want to check if the variable has a string value `'undefined'`